# Laravel delete method: how to delete related files

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4.2

I have some issue with my Laravel 4.2 project.
I have a `Photo` model and a `Service` model with relationship `Service hasMany Photos`.

Photos (files) are stored in `public/upload/` directory.
When I delete photo (method `delete()` in `Photo`) the file is removed form the server (code shown below) but when I delete `Service` (method `delete()` in `Service`) database entry for `Service` and all it's photos (DB records) are removed but files are not even when I trigger `$this->photos()->delete();`

I placed `Log::debug('photos->delete() fired');` in `Photo->delete()` method and it's fired if I call it directly, and when I try to launch it via `Service->delete()` there are no log entries. 
I have no idea why it acts like this. Can anyone help?

This is my code `Service`:

```
 public function photos()
 {
    return $this->hasMany('Photo');
 }
 public function delete()
 { 
    $this->photos()->delete();
    parent::delete();
 }
```

And `Photo`:

```
public function delete()
{
    Log::debug('photos->delete() fired');
    $file = public_path().'/upload/'.$this->filename;
    if(File::isFile($file)){
       File::delete($file);
    }
    parent::delete();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

First of all, no need to `overload` the `delete()` methods.

In your DB, make the relationship between Service and Photo, and onDelete cascade.

For deleting files, add an event listener to your Photo model:

```
class Photo extends Eloquent {


public static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    Photo::deleted(function($photo){
         $file = public_path().'/upload/'.$photo->filename;
         if(File::isFile($file)){
              File::delete($file);
         }
    });
}
```

}

Comment: I cant change DB schema so setting `onDelete cascade` is not possible. As I tested your solution doesn't work without database changes. Thanx anyway

Comment: The solution I have provided for the file deletion part does not depend on DB changes.

Answer (score 1):

You can create Observer Pattern for deleting event in model refer this [link](https://bosnadev.com/2014/12/28/laravel-model-observers/)

Comment: It is working if I delete model directly `Photo->delete()` but when it is launched via `Service()` (`$this->photos()->delete()`) it doesn't run at all.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `File` variable name for your Model and Controller to avoid conflicts. `$somefile` variable or any(you name it) will receive data from controller, so you will take a `filename` of the file. So must have `filename` field in your Table for this code

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use File; 

class SomeFile extends Model {

public static function boot()
        {
            parent::boot();

            static::deleted(function($somefile)
            {
                $path  =   public_path().'/uploads/';

                $filename  = $somefile->filename;

                if (File::exists($path.$filename)) {
                    File::delete($path.$filename);
                }
            });
        }
}
```